# Assembly MASM loop jumping without adding final value of Array

Tags: assembly, masm

```
.data
j SDWORD ?
k SDWORD ?
array1 SDWORD 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
19, 20
sum SDWORD ?


.code
_main PROC
mov j, 3 ; Setting J into the Array
mov k, 6 ; Setting K into the Array
mov edx, 2 ; Setting the index number for the starting position (J)

sumArray1:
mov eax, [array1+edx*4]
cmp eax, k 
jg array2
add sum, eax
inc edx
jmp SumArray1

array2:
INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
_main ENDP
END
```

&sum is at a value of 12 when the program terms, meaning that for some reason it is not adding the value of K before jumping out of the loop. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the value are in hex xD

Comment: If you want to sum up array[2] to array[6], you need to compare edx (which is i), not eax (which is (array[i]) )

Answer (score 0):

There are no issues with your code that I can see. Here is what I'm seeing after stepping over your loop:

[image: no issues here]

Have you stepped through your code line by line to see what might be happening?